# Azure Function Python Exceptions not logging correctly to App Insights

Tags: python-3.x, azure-functions, azure-application-insights

I am seeing some unexpected behaviour when using `logging.error(..)` in a Python Azure Function.. essentially, the error is getting logged as a trace, which seems a bit odd.. it's the same w. `logging.exception(..)` too.

Some simple sample code:

```
import logging
import azure.functions as func

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')
    logging.error('[Error] I am an error.')

    return func.HttpResponse()
```

When this is executed, the following winds up in Application Insights.. why is this not available under `exceptions`?

[image]

Query for ref:

```
union *
| where operation_Id == 'ca8f0c7d7798a54996b486940641b159'
| project operation_Id, message, severityLevel, itemType, customDimensions.['LogLevel']
```

Any clues as to what I am doing wrong??

Answer (score 2):

> I am seeing some unexpected behaviour when using in a Python Azure
> Function.. essentially, the error is getting logged as a trace, which
> seems a bit odd.. it's the same w.
> too.logging.error(..)logging.exception(..)

These will be classified as trace in Application Insights, the only manifestation is log level (at least Application Insights is like this). If you need this to classify it as 'exceptions' in Application Insights, you need to use below code(and don't deal with it, once you use try-except and other processing, you will enter the trace again):

`raise Exception('Boom!')`

But this will stop the function, so it doesn't make much sense. I suggest you search for ‘trace’ and set filters to extract exception or error levels.

Comment: yes, I am now searching for trace and filtering on the logLevel, but I am convinced this isn't the same behaviour as under C# .. I will test it later. Thanks for confirming I wasn't doing something daft though.

Comment: Using `raise` works if you have some catastrophic failure that means the function can't complete. This also logs it as an exception in apps insights. Otherwise it only gets logged as a trace with logging.error or logging.exception

Answer (score 1):

Currently, the only way to log messages to `exceptions table` in application insights, is that put the `logger.exception()` method in the try except code block. Like below:

```
try:
    result = 1/0
except Exception:
    logger.exception("it is an exception 88 which is in the try block...")
```

then in application insights, you can find the messages in exceptions table:

[image]

There is [an issue](https://github.com/census-instrumentation/opencensus-python/issues/1005) about this, let us wait for the feedback from MS.

Comment: that is interesting, thanks.

funny thing is is DID originally do logger.Exception in a try except code block, and it still didn't work - maybe I will re-check as it was a few weeks ago now.

Comment: @m1nkeh, and you can also see the feedback of [that issue](https://github.com/census-instrumentation/opencensus-python/issues/1005#issuecomment-768423234). `logger.error` will always flow into traces. `logger.exception` will flow into exception table, but currently, you need to put it in the `try-except` code block.

Comment: @m1nkeh, since `logger.exception` can only be used in try-except code block, and it can work in that case, could you please accept it as answer?